# how to display multiple data from database in single input

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, input

Is there any way i can display data from database in a single input form.

So when i call all the data in the database using

```
<input id="text" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
```

this is how the data is displayed

```
<input id="text" value="Name1"/>
<input id="text" value="Name2"/>
<input id="text" value="Name3"/>
```

But I want the data to display like this

```
<input id="text" value="Name1,Name2,Name3"/>
```

Please help

Comment: GRoup_concat the name

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format of `$name;` you can do some manipulation of it to get the output format you want.

If it's an array, you can use:

```
<?php echo $name[0] . ", " . $name[1] . ", " . $name[2];?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $name['Name1'] . ", " . $name['Name2'] . ", " . $name['Name3'];?>
```

My sense is it's an array, judging from the output you're getting.  However, if say it was a string with a space between Name1, Name2, and Name3, you could use:

```
$names = explode(" ", $name);
...
echo $names
```

Good luck, and I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate the desired result using "." operator.

Your final code may look like this

```
<input id="text" 
    value="<?php 
    
             $name=$name1.','.$name2.','.$name3;
             echo $name; 
    
          ?>"
    
>
```